# One form on dual monitors, full screen

Tags: c#, .net

I'm in the process of making a screensaver for a non-profit business. I have everything done and working except the main desk uses dual monitors, and the Windows form won't display on both monitors. My code is below (the correct dual monitor resolution is detected). The form size reports correctly for dual monitors - but the actual form doesn't display as extended on the second monitor.

My code below is in the Form_Load event. Any help in getting this to work right would be appreciated.

```
Screen[] monitors = Screen.AllScreens;

foreach (Screen screen in monitors)
{
    totalwidth += screen.WorkingArea.Width;
}

this.Size = new Size(totalwidth, ClientSize.Height);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do more than what you have.

In essence you will have to create a new form for each screen

**Program**

```
for (int i = Screen.AllScreens.GetLowerBound(0);  
     i <= Screen.AllScreens.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
       System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new frmScreenSaver(i));
```

**Example form constructor**

```
public frmScreenSaver(int scrn)
{
  ...
  ScreenNumber = scrn;
  ...
}
```

**Example form OnLoad event**

```
private void frmScreenSaver_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  ...
  // fit the screen
  Bounds = Screen.AllScreens[ScreenNumber].Bounds;
  // hide the cursor... seems appropriate
  Cursor.Hide(); 
  // make it TopMost
  TopMost = true;
  ...
}
```

There are more caveats with screen savers, however this should point you in the right direction

also, you could probably just pass in the bounds, instead of the index

Comment: Thank you! This got me moving correctly. I appreciate it!